# Need to move from formatted string to binary buffers

Tags: c++, c, file-io, binaryfiles

I am using formatted std::string to store my intermediate buffers before dumping them in a file.

Now I want to write my intermediate data in binary buffers as I want to dump my file in binary format. Which type do I need to use for these binary buffers.

Take note that these intermediate records are formatted data in a string. By formatted data, I mean string made by call of sprintf with %s,%d etc.

Comment: When you say formatted data, you mean what exactly?

Comment: btse, I mean string made by call of sprintf with %s,%d etc to store data values.

Comment: You should show an example of what you have and what you want

Comment: If your data are strings, you could use a `std::stringstream`. This is a better solution than using an string class.

Answer (score -1):

Here is to convert to to binary.

[Conversion of Char to Binary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863499/conversion-of-char-to-binary-in-c)

and to convert back to char:

[Convert binary format string to int, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343099/convert-binary-format-string-to-int-in-c)

:D