# Converting Binary std::string to int in binary representation

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble converting a 16-bit std::string to an int that can hold the exact binary number of the string. I've been messing around with atoi and bitset but they converting to deciamls or take off leading zeros is there a way to do this

```
std::string str = "0011101100010101";
int num = 0;
.
.
.
num = 0011101100010101  // now equals
```

Comment: Just use `std::bitset`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary format string to int, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343099/convert-binary-format-string-to-int-in-c)

Comment: @NineBerry in C++ it can be done much simpler that writing a loop explicitly

Comment: Note that integer variables hold numbers and not number representations, so there will be no leading zeros and the default output will output the number using the decimal system, not the binary system.

Comment: "take off leading zeros". There is no such thing as leading zeroes in integer represantation, only in string representation.

Comment: @Slava I would suggest using the answer that uses strtol.

Comment: @NineBerry you may suggest to look there, but I do not think that answer for C makes this question duplicate. It can be and should be done differently in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::bitset

```
std::string str = "0011101100010101";
auto number = static_cast<uint16_t>(std::bitset<16>{ str }.to_ulong( ));
```

Or use a literal if you don't need a string

```
uint16_t b = 0b0011101100010101;
```

Comment: Note that [binary literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) are introduced in C++14

Comment: That is true. The major compilers(g++, clang, msvc...) support it, plus many embedded ones have as an extension.  I guess if you are stuck, but two ways there too