# Is it undefined behavior to take the address of an uninitialized pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

N1570 states that this is undefined behavior:

> §J.2/1 The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used
>   while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8).

And in this case, our pointer has an indeterminate value:

> §6.7.9/10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not
>   initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that
>   has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;

I then presume the following test program exhibits undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char * ptr;
    printf("%p", (void*)&ptr);
}
```

My motivating concern is the `strtol` function. First, let me quote the parts of N1570 related to the `endptr` parameter:

> §7.22.1.4/5 If the subject sequence has the expected form and the
>   value of base is zero, the sequence of characters starting with the
>   first digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to the
>   rules of 6.4.4.1. [...] A pointer to the final string is stored in the
>   object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is not a null
>   pointer.
>
> §7.22.1.4/7 If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the
>   expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of `nptr` is
>   stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is
>   not a null pointer.

This implies that `endptr` needs to be pointing to an object, and also that `endptr` is at some point dereferenced. For example, [this implementation does so](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/strtol.c):

```
if (endptr != 0)
    *endptr = (char *)(any ? s - 1 : nptr);
```

Yet, [this highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/117870/3920237) as well as [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) both show `endptr` being passed to `strtol` uninitialized. Is there an exception which makes this not undefined behavior?

Comment: You are not using the value of the pointer, only the address of the variable that stores the pointer value.  Which is well-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression:

`&ptr`

the address of the `&` operand, i. e., the address of the `ptr` object is yielded but the `ptr` object is never evaluated.

(C11, 6.3.2.1p2) "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion."

Answer (score 9):

The pointer's value and its address are not the same.

```
void *foo;
```

That pointer has an undefined value, but the address of `foo`, i.e. the value of `&foo`, must be well-determined (since otherwise we can't access it).

At least that's my intuitive understanding, I didn't dig up the standard now, I just think you're mis-reading it.

When talking about code, the two are sometimes confused ("what's the address of that pointer?" *can* mean "what's the value of that pointer, what address is it pointing to?") but they are really distinct.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not undefined behaviour. Only `ptr` is uninitialized and has indeterminate value but `&ptr` has a proper value.

What the standard quote on `strtol` says:

*...If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.*

That above quote is talks about a call like this:

```
strtol(str, 0, 10);
```

The call in the man page and the linked answer are perfectly fine.

Comment: As `NULL` is normally `#define`d as 0, and the standard makes explicit allowance for calling `strtol` with `**endptr` as `NULL`, why can't you do `strtol(str, 0, 10);`?

Comment: My answer is a bit misleading...It's in reply to *...provided that endptr is not a null pointer.* Of course, it does allow it to be `0`. I'll edit that part.

Answer (score 2):

See this example

```
char * ptr;
```

Since `ptr` is not pointing to any object, dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. But when you pass its address to `strtol`, having syntax

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

in statement

```
long parsed = strtol("11110111", &ptr, 2);
```

the `endptr` parameter of `strtol` is pointing to object `ptr` and derefeencing it will not invoke any UB.

Answer (score 0):

I only have access to N1256 but I will be surprised if there is any material change.

The most relevant section is "6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators"

And in particular paragraph 3 (my emphasis):

> Semantics
>
> 3 **The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.** If the
>   operand has type ''type'', the result has type ''pointer to type''. If
>   the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator
>   nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and
>   the result is not an lvalue. Similarly, if the operand is the result
>   of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is
>   implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator
>   were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator.
>   Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function
>   designated by its operand.

None of the cited paragraphs in the OP apply because as many have pointed out. The value of something and its address are very different.

I would argue that the absence of any restriction on & regarding uninitialized values taking their address is permitted (by the absence of prohibition).

NOTE: We all know it's fine but it's very rare to find statements in these standards that explicitly say "Yes you can do so & so."