# converting string to int in a literal sense

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

Hello :) I'm trying to do a conversion of a string to an int using c++.
I have tried using stol, stoll, and strtol functions and (maybe I was using them wrong) but they didn't seem to preserve my string in a literal sense.

Question: How would I go about literally converting a string containing 0s and 1s to an int so that my int is *exactly* like my string was.

Example:

```
string s = "00010011";
int digits = 0; // convert int to: digits = 00010011;
```

Appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string of 1s and 0s into binary value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117844/converting-string-of-1s-and-0s-into-binary-value)

Comment: `int` stores numerical values. `10011` and `010011` are the same value.  what youre describing is actually storing a string... so stick with your string

Comment: You probably aren't going to be able to preserve leading 0's when going from string -> int -> string. Any of the parsing functions you mentioned can create an integral rep of a string, within reason.

Comment: @OldProgrammer not a duplicate, the person asking their question in your link is asking about a conversion from string to binary.

Comment: Actual numbers (int, for instance) don't have leading zeros, so it can't possibly look as you want. If you don't understand that integers (other than zero itself) can't start with a zero, you should probably go take a tutorial on basic number and math skills before writing code.

Comment: @KenWhite Hey, thanks for the reply! At times I have a tendency to forget the basics -- all apart of learning, right?. I was looking for some suggestions on what to use if an int wasn't feasible here, thats all...  Oh, and your tutorial suggestion was cute ;)

Comment: @M.M I'm thinking I'm going to have to stick with a string here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

```
string s = "00010011";
int digits = 0; // convert int to: digits = 00010011;

std::bitset<32> bst(s);
digits = static_cast<int>(bst.to_ulong());
```

To be more pedantic about size, instead of `std::bitset<32>`, you can do:

```
std::bitset<(sizeof(int) * 8)> bst(s);
```

To get back the string *(well, not exactly)*:

```
std::string sp = std::bitset<32>(digits).to_string();
```

---

Additionally, to trim off the leading zeros from, `sp`:

```
auto x = sp.find_first_not_of('0');
if(x != string::npos)
    sp = sp.substr(x);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I will look into trying your approach :)